# Put arguments in slots in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I've made a class named MyWindow which inherits from QWidget to create a window. Here is the content of mywindow.h:

```
class MyWindow: public QWidget{
    public:
        MyWindow(QString title,QString icon,int w = 600,int h = 400);
        int getWidth() const;
        int getHeight() const;
    public slots:
        void openDialogBox(QString title,QString message);
    private:
        int m_width;
        int m_height;
};
```

There is a openDialogBox slot which takes the title and the message of the dialog box as arguments.

I've made a menu bar which basically looks like this:

```
MyWindow myWindow("Example window",QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/icon.png");
QMenuBar menuBar(&myWindow);
menuBar.setGeometry(0,0,myWindow.getWidth(),menuBar.geometry().height());
QMenu *fileMenu = new QMenu("&File");
QAction *fileMenu_open = fileMenu->addAction("&Open");
MyWindow::connect(fileMenu_open,&QAction::triggered,&myWindow,&MyWindow::openDialogBox);
```

In the last line, I would like to send arguments to the slot `&MyWindow::openDialogBox`. I tried to do:

```
MyWindow::connect(fileMenu_open,&QAction::triggered,&myWindow,&MyWindow::openDialogBox("Title","Hello, this is a message"));
```

but it didn't work (I don't need you to explain why it didn't work, I already know why). How to do this properly so that it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the [New Signal Slot Syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax), I would suggest using a c++11 lambda instead of a slot, and call the desired function inside your slot, here is how your [connect](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5) call would look like:

```
QObject::connect(fileMenu_open, &QAction::triggered, &myWindow, [&myWindow](){
    myWindow.openDialogBox("Title","Hello, this is a message");
});
```

Note that `openDialogBox` is not required to be a slot this way, it can be any normal function.

If your compiler does not support C++11 lambda expression, you might have to declare a slot that does not take any argument, and connect to that slot. And inside that slot call your function with the desired arguments. . .

Answer (score 0):

Use lambdas

```
QObject::connect(fileMenu_open, &QAction::triggered, &myWindow, [QWeakPointer<MyWindow> weakWindow = myWindow]()
{
    weakWindow->openDialogBox("Title","Hello, this is a message");
});
```

QWeakPointer is used in case your class is moved, so the "old" myWindow is a dangling pointer
If your class won't be moved, just capture myWindow.
Note that my code needs C++14 to declare a variable in the lambda capture

Comment: *QWeakPointer objects can only be created by assignment from a QSharedPointer.*, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qweakpointer.html#details). `myWindow` is not a `QSharedPointer`.

Comment: if you are worried about `myWindow` being copied or moved, then `QObject`s [cannot be](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#no-copy-constructor-or-assignment-operator) copied. If you are worried about `myWindow` being a dangling pointer (if it is destructed), then the connection is automatically disconnected when the `context` object is destroyed, see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect-5), and the context object in your answer is `&myWindow`. I can't see any point of trying to use `QWeakPointer` here.

Comment: Yeah, I meant QPointer. And your link only says that QObjects cannot be copied, not moved.